# How to add individual objects to django haystack?

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I have a search index that I have created using Solr. I want to add individual django objects to the search index.

To remove objects from the solr database we use **remove_object**.

```
some = SomFooModel.objects.get(pk=1)
foo = FooIndex()
foo.remove_object(some) #This works
```

To add it, is there something like **add_object** or a work around here ?

What I want is.

```
foo.add_object(some). # there is no such thing
```

This also does not work. It does not add the object to index.

```
foo.update_object(some)
```

I have tried reading the django-haystack documentation but there seems to be nothing that might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not read the documentation well enough as a result I messed up on the QuerySet part.

```
foo.update_object(some)
```

The above does add the object to the index. Its just that I was not searching for it properly. 
I was searching for the object after removing it in the following way.

```
SearchQuerySet().filter(foo=some.foo)
```

This gave a empty query set always.

```
SearchQuerySet().models(SomFooModel).filter(foo = some.foo)
```

This gives the correct result.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276957/django-haystack-search-by-django-model-pk)